# What is the input of unidecode?

Tags: string, perl, unicode, utf-8

From the [perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm):

> What Text::Unidecode provides is a function, unidecode(...) that takes
>   Unicode data

What does `Unicode data` mean in this sentence? Is it the Perl string? i.e. the Encode::is_utf8 will be true if called on the input string or is the unicode bytes i.e. the result of `encode`?

Comment: It takes a string of Unicode code points, such as the one returned by `decode`.

Comment: @ikegami:What you say is something that I can understand as explanation.I am not sure if amon is telling me the same thing but I am failing to understand his answer

Comment: He is saying the same thing. He means "Unicode code points" when he said "Unicode characters". (There's no such thing as a "Unicode character".)

Comment: @ikegami When I said “Unicode character” I meant “A codepoint that can't be represented in ASCII”. — I edited my answer to remove the confusing notion of such a simple thing like a “character”. (This is an instance where I'd really love a type system in Perl, it would make explaining encodings & stuff far easier)

Comment: @amon, Yes, some semantic flags would be nice here. Something like: binary -vs- native -vs- code points -vs- unknown.

Answer (score 4):

Text::Unidecode does not do any de- or encoding. It *transliterates* a string possibly containing non-ASCII codepoints to a string only using ASCII codepoints. This is not the same as encoding the string in UTF-8.

Transliteration means that a similar-sounding text is emitted. For example, Unicode but not ASCII has umlauts like `ü`. This could be transliterated to the string `ue` (`\x75\x65`) or `u`. If the character `ü` were encoded as UTF-8, we would get `\xC3\xBC`.

If the input contains only codepoints in the ASCII range, the output string is equivalent to the input (string-compares equal). For such an input string, the utf8-flag may or may not be set; this is *irrelevant* for the Perl programmer.

Example transliterations:

```
"über cool" → "uber cool"
"1 · 2"     → "1 * 2"
"€0.99"     → "EU0.99"
"© 2011"    → "(c) 2011"
"¼"         → "1/4"
"pure ASCII"→ "pure ASCII"
```

Comment: `It transliterates a string possibly containing Unicode characters` this means a string that `Encode::is_utf8` returns `true` for it?

Comment: The utf8-Flag indicates which internal storage format is used for the string. The value has no user-visible effect. Please forget `is_utf8` (which returns the value of this flag). If the input string contains a code point > `FF`, then the flag will be set. Otherwise (all CPs fit into one byte) the flag may or may not be set. In the output of `unidecode`, no codepoint will exceed `7F` (the largest ASCII character).

Comment: @Cratylus, Why do you keep bringing up the **internal** storage format. Forget about `is_utf8` already!

Comment: @ikegami:I am sorry, I don't do it intentionally. I am trying to find a model to understand these better

Comment: @Cratylus, My point is that the internal storage format should not be in any of your models. It has nothing to do with encoding/decoding. Bringing it up just complicates everything, since we have to start by saying how it has no bearing on the situation

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for Text::Unicode, under "Caveats", it appears that this phrase is incorrect:

*Make sure that the input data really is a utf8 string.*

UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding, whereas Text::Unidecode only accepts a fixed-length (two-byte) encoding for each character.  So that sentence should read:

*Make sure that the input data really is a string of two-byte Unicode characters.*

This is also referred to as UCS-2.

If you want to convert strings which really are utf8, you would do it like so:

```
my $decode_status = utf8::decode($input_to_be_converted);
my $converted_string = unidecode ($input_to_be_converted);
```